# How to get previous image?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a gallery based on this http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/simplest-jquery-slideshow tutorial and a problem arouse - i cant select previous image. Can somebody help?

The code is simple:

```
jQuery('#next_image').click(function(){
    jQuery('#archive_gallery :first-child').hide().next('img').show().end().appendTo('#archive_gallery');
});

<div id="archive_gallery">
    <img src="01.jpg">
    <img src="02.jpg" style="display: none;">
    <img src="03.jpg" style="display: none;">
    <img src="04.jpg" style="display: none;">
    <img src="05.jpg" style="display: none;">
    <img src="06.jpg" style="display: none;">
    <img src="07.jpg" style="display: none;">
    <img src="08.jpg" style="display: none;">
    <img src="09.jpg" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

---

## Found a solution:

```
jQuery('#archive_gallery :last-child').prependTo('#archive_gallery').show().next('img').hide().end();
```

Comment: Can you please post the HTML you are using.